# How to show irreducible closed subsets of Spec are vanishing sets of primes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

I would like to show if $R$ is a comm ring, and $Y \subset\operatorname{Spec}R$
is a closed irreducible subset,
then there is a prime ideal $p \subset R$ such that $Y = V(p)$,
i.e. $Y = \{ q \in \operatorname{Spec}R : q \supseteq p\}$.

I'm not quite sure where to begin, other than saying

- $Y = V(I)$ for some ideal $I$ because $Y$ is closed;
- and $I$ cannot be factored into a product of ideals $J,J'$ each with vanishing set different from $V(I)$, since $Y$ is irreducible and $V(JJ') = V(J) \cup V(J')$.

Would anyone know how to approach this?

Note: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4153417/a-closed-set-in-operatornamespecr-is-irreducible-iff-ix-is-prime?rq=1) seems related, but what I would like to show is roughly a converse to what that question is trying to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, if $Y$ is closed, $Y=V(I)$ for some $I$, and one can assume that $I$ is a radical ideal. Suppose $V(I)$ is irreducible, and suppose $f,g\in R$ and $fg\in I$. If $X_{fg}$ denotes the usual basic open set of primes not containing $fg$, then
$$
\emptyset=X_{fg}\cap V(I)=(X_f\cap V(I))\cap (X_g\cap V(I))
$$
as $X_{fg}=X_f\cap X_g$.

Since $V(I)$ is irreducible, at least one of $X_f\cap V(I)$ or $X_g\cap V(I)$ must be empty, since two nonempty open subsets of an irreducible space cannot be disjoint. If $X_f\cap V(I)=\emptyset$, then $f$ is contained in every prime ideal containing $I$, i.e., $f$ is in the radical of $I$, i.e., $f\in I$ since $I$ is radical. Similarly, if $X_g\cap V(I)$ is empty, $g\in I$. In any case, $I$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Comment: +1, nice answer. For completeness, if I'm remembering correctly, $Y = V(I)$ for $I = \cap_{P \in Y} P$, and this proof shows $I$ is prime when $Y$ is irreducible. In this way, the maps $P \mapsto V(P), Y \mapsto \cap_{P \in Y} P$ define a bijective correspondence between elements of $Spec(R)$ and irreducible closed subsets of $Spec(R)$, which restricts to a bijection between irreducible components of $Spec(R)$ and minimal prime ideals.

Answer (score 0):

$V(x^2)$ is closed and irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x]$, but not prime.

You're probably looking for [primary decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition).

Comment: Here I meant $V(p)$ as in just a set of primes on which all of $I$ vanishes, not as the actual scheme $\operatorname{Spec} R/p$. I'm interested in showing every irreducible closed subset of an affine scheme has a generic point.